# Are Lambda Layers supported for Lambdas deployed to Greengrass?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to deploy a binary utility along with my Python-based lambda to a Greengrass group.

Using a layer seemed like a natural way to accomplish this. No errors are encountered during the deployment, but I cannot find any evidence that the layer exists on the edge device (Ubuntu 18.04).

I have also been unable to find any documentation that confirms or denies layers work with Greengrass.

To move forward, I am bundling the utility within the Lambda deployment package itself. This seems workable, but a layer seems more flexible...

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just from my experience, no, Layers do not get pushed to the Greengrass host, so if your lambda function depends on libraries in a layer, it will fail to run, even though deployments will go through without issue.

AWS I believe is no longer updating Greengrass V1, as they're focused on Greengrass V2.  So I doubt this issue will get addressed.  As a workaround, package everything within the lambda function and don't use layers for those functions getting pushed to Greengrass.